# URLs amigables con form -> submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

Cómo puedo usar las URLS amigables con el 
**form -> submit**

Ya tengo las URLS amigables hechas en el .htaccess ,funcionan!

Pero al presionar el boton SUBMIT me lleva a la URL normal (GET)

```
http://www.mi.web/stats.php?Jugador=Abcedario
```

Pero al poner la url directa si funciona

```
http://www.mi.web/players/Abcedario
```

me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para Reedicionar el SUBMIT a la URL amigable

**FORM**

```
<form method="get" action="stats.php">
    <label>Jugador: </label><input type="text" name="Jugador"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Buscar">
```

**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^players/(\w+)$ stats.php?Jugador=$1
```

Comment: Me gustaría ver cómo tienes puesto el action en el form.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este ejemplo intentalo asi:

```
#Aqui lo que se hace es quitar la extension del archivo en este ejemplo es .html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

#creando reglas de reescritura colocas la url amigable y el archivo que hace referencia
    RewriteRule ^url-amigable-form    file-referencia.php
</IfModule>
```

y en el formulario haces referencia al "url-amigable-form"